# Have Schemas in Redoc side menu

Tags: html, documentation, jsonschema, redoc

Redoc is a great tool, but I'm struggling to understand how it works. Currently I've been tasked with copying some docs from api-docs.io to be self served using [redoc](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc).

However, my issue is that the schemas aren't appearing in the side bar as they do on the api-docs site. I'm not sure how I can get models to show on the side as well... And I'm fairly new to api documentation. You can also check out how the models are displayed [here](http://redocly.github.io/redoc/#tag/pet_model). And see another example below.

[image]

I've taken a look to see if this is a feature of redoc and came across [this merged PR](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/pull/681) which (based on the discussion in the PR's issue) states that we should add an html element, `SchemaDefinition`. I am using the basic html file (suggested in the readme of the redoc repo), but we want to use a json schema (which is referenced with `spec-url`) to render the docs on redoc so I'm struggling to understand how I can manipulate the side bar using just the html element.

Maybe it's just my understanding of how redoc works that is lacking. If you feel that's the case, a quick explanation would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the json with additional information.

Sample json (without sidebar model section): https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.json

Add to "tags" array

```
{
  "name": "pet_model",
  "description": <SchemaDefinition schemaRef="#/components/schemas/Pet" />,
  "x-displayName": "Pet"
},
{
  "name": "user_model",  
  "description": <SchemaDefinition schemaRef="#/components/schemas/User" />,
  "x-displayName": "User"
}
```

Then to group the sidebar add the [x-tagGroups](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/blob/master/docs/redoc-vendor-extensions.md#x-tagGroups) extension

```
...
"tags": [...],

"x-tagGroups": [{
  "name": "Api",
  "tags": ["pet", "store", "user"]
},
{
  "name": "Models",
  "tags": ["pet_model", "user_model"]
}],

"paths": ...
```